# Why is the training error increasing with each epoch, linear regression implemented using tensorflow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow and have implemented a linear regression model. The dataset I am using is available in https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Housing. At each epoch the loss is increasing.
Here is my code -

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

A = np.loadtxt("housing.data",dtype=np.float32)
s = A.shape
B = A[:,:s[1]-1]
C = A[:,-1]
C = C.reshape(s[0],1)

W = tf.Variable(tf.ones([s[1]-1,1]))
b = tf.Variable([.3],tf.float32)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape = (None,s[1]-1))
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape = (None,1))

linear_model = tf.matmul(x,W) + b
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(linear_model - y)) # sum of the squares
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

for i in xrange(1000):
    sess.run(train,feed_dict={x:B,y:C})


curr_W, curr_b, curr_loss  = sess.run([W, b, loss], feed_dict={x:B, y:C})
print("W: %s b: %s loss: %s"%(curr_W, curr_b, curr_loss))
```

Answer (score 3):

This problem is called [**exploding gradient**](https://deepai.org/machine-learning-glossary-and-terms/exploding-gradient-problem). Your loss increases for just a few iterations before reaching NaN. The problem seems to be that the initial loss is very big (`10^13`), hence probably its gradient too, which creates an update that is way too big, puts you in an even worse spot for your parameters, and eventually produces `NaN`s gradient backpropagation (probably through an overflow somehow, or because it produces a value `0` somewhere and divides by it).

You can fix this by lowering your learning rate, which will compensate for this huge gradient values from start. `0.000001` fixes the problem for me (this is a very low value though compared to usual learning rates, so it is a bit of a problem to have to use that only for the first steps). However, since it's just for the start, you might want a higher learning rate for the rest of your training. You can change it after a few steps, or something more robust would be to [clip your gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44798131/7456923).

**EDIT**

Also, you should initilaize your weights randomly:

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([s[1]-1,1], stddev=0.1))
```

It learns quite well for me with random optimization, gradient clipping:

```
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.0005)

gvs = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss)
capped_gvs = [(tf.clip_by_value(grad, -1., 1.), var) for grad, var in gvs]
train = optimizer.apply_gradients(capped_gvs)
```

`10000` iterations, and `learning rate = 0.0005`, but you should probably use a decaying learning rate, starting there and smaller after a while.

Comment: For me the loss is very large from the first iteration and it has a increasing trend and after first 2-3 iterations it becomes 'NaN'

Comment: Then it's the same as for me, my answer should work (possibly you might have to use an even smaller learning rate than me)