# Super high cost Tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm trying to make some price prediction on a kaggle dataset with Tensorflow.
My Neural network is learning, but, my cost function is really high and my predictions are far from the real output.
I tried to change my network by adding or removing some layers, neurons and activations functions.
I tried a lot with my hyper-parameters but that don't change so much things.
I don't think that the problem come from my datas, I checked on kaggle and that's the ones that most people uses.

If you have any idea why my cost is so high and how to reduce it and if you could explain it to me, it would be really great !

Her's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\User\Documents\TENSORFLOW\Prediction prix\train2.csv", sep=';')
df.head()

df = df.loc[:, ['OverallQual', 'GrLivArea', 'GarageCars', 'TotalBsmtSF', 'FullBath', 'SalePrice']]

df = df.replace(np.nan, 0)

df

%matplotlib inline
plt = sns.pairplot(df)
plt

df = shuffle(df)

df_train = df[0:1000]
df_test = df[1001:1451]

inputX = df_train.drop('SalePrice', 1).as_matrix()
inputX = inputX.astype(int)

inputY = df_train.loc[:, ['SalePrice']].as_matrix()
inputY = inputY.astype(int)

inputX_test = df_test.drop('SalePrice', 1).as_matrix()
inputX_test = inputX_test.astype(int)

inputY_test = df_test.loc[:, ['SalePrice']].as_matrix()
inputY_test = inputY_test.astype(int)



# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.01
training_epochs = 1000
batch_size = 500
display_step = 50

n_samples = inputX.shape[0]


x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 5])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])


def add_layer(inputs, in_size, out_size, activation_function=None):
    Weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([in_size, out_size], stddev=0.1))
    biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1, out_size]) + 0.1)
    Wx_plus_b = tf.matmul(inputs, Weights) + biases
    if activation_function is None:
        output = Wx_plus_b
    else:
        output = activation_function(Wx_plus_b)
    return output


l1 = add_layer(x, 5, 3, activation_function=tf.nn.relu)

pred = add_layer(l1, 3, 1)


# Mean squared error
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(pred-y, 2))/(2*n_samples)
# Gradient descent
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)


# Initializing the variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()


# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    # Training cycle
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        avg_cost = 0.
        total_batch = batch_size
        # Loop over all batches
        for i in range(total_batch):
            # Run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
            _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: inputX,
                                                          y: inputY})
            # Compute average loss
            avg_cost += c / total_batch
        # Display logs per epoch step
        if epoch % display_step == 0:
            print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "cost=", \
                "{:.9f}".format(avg_cost))
    print("Optimization Finished!")

    # Test model
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(pred,y)
    # Calculate accuracy
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
    print("Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({x: inputX, y: inputY}))
    print(sess.run(pred, feed_dict={x: inputX_test}))
```

Epoch: 0001 cost= 10142407502702304395526144.000000000

Epoch: 0051 cost= 3256106752.000019550

Epoch: 0101 cost= 3256106752.000019550

Epoch: 0151 cost= 3256106752.000019550

Epoch: 0201 cost= 3256106752.000019550

...

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Could you show the rest of your code please ?

Comment: Edited, all the code is here now

Comment: Why do you have `total_batch = batch_size` ? Should it not be  `total_batch = n_samples / batch_size`, so that `total_batch` batches of size `batch_size` make an epoch ? And in the feed_dict, you should use only `batch_size` samples at a time, not all your training data (that's what a batch is...).

Comment: Two things : First, try 13 hidden layers instead of 3, because you want more capability to fit the data.  Second, try predicting log(**y**) instead of predicting **y**, because prices are not linearly distributed but instead are geometrically distributed.

Comment: Don't you mean 13 neurons instead ? 13 hidden layers seams really large.. When I try to predict log, my cost become 'Nan' :
`l1 = add_layer(x, 5, 13, activation_function=tf.nn.relu)`
`out = add_layer(l1, 13, 1)`
`pred = tf.log(out)`

`cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(pred-tf.log(y), 2))/(2*n_samples)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see couple of problems with the implementation:

1. Inputs are not scaled.
     Use sklearn StandardScaler to scale the inputs inputX, inputY (and also  inputX_text and inputY_text) to make it zero mean and unit variance. You can use the inverse_transform to convert the outputs back to proper scale again.

   ```
   sc = StandardScaler().fit(inputX)
   inputX = sc.transform(inputX)
   inputX_test = sc.transform(inputX_test)
   ```
2. The batch_size is too large, you are passing the entire set as a single batch. This should not cause the particular problem you are facing, but for better convergence try with reduced batch size. Implement a get_batch() generator function and do the following:

   ```
   for batch_X, batch_Y in get_batch(input_X, input_Y, batch_size):
      _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_X,
                                                 y: batch_Y})
   ```
3. Try smaller Weights initialization (stddev) if you still see issues.

WORKING CODE BELOW:

```
inputX = df_train.drop('SalePrice', 1).as_matrix()
inputX = inputX.astype(int)
sc = StandardScaler().fit(inputX)
inputX = sc.transform(inputX)

inputY = df_train.loc[:, ['SalePrice']].as_matrix()
inputY = inputY.astype(int)
sc1 = StandardScaler().fit(inputY)
inputY = sc1.transform(inputY)

inputX_test = df_test.drop('SalePrice', 1).as_matrix()
inputX_test = inputX_test.astype(int)
inputX_test = sc.transform(inputX_test)

inputY_test = df_test.loc[:, ['SalePrice']].as_matrix()
inputY_test = inputY_test.astype(int)
inputY_test = sc1.transform(inputY_test)

learning_rate = 0.01
training_epochs = 1000
batch_size = 50
display_step = 50

n_samples = inputX.shape[0]

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 5])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])

def get_batch(inputX, inputY, batch_size):
  duration = len(inputX)
  for i in range(0,duration//batch_size):
    idx = i*batch_size
    yield inputX[idx:idx+batch_size], inputY[idx:idx+batch_size]


def add_layer(inputs, in_size, out_size, activation_function=None):
  Weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([in_size, out_size], stddev=0.005))
  biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1, out_size]))
  Wx_plus_b = tf.matmul(inputs, Weights) + biases
  if activation_function is None:
    output = Wx_plus_b
  else:
    output = activation_function(Wx_plus_b)
  return output


l1 = add_layer(x, 5, 3, activation_function=tf.nn.relu)

pred = add_layer(l1, 3, 1)

# Mean squared error
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(tf.subtract(pred, y), 2))
# Gradient descent
optimizer =   tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)


# Initializing the variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()


# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
 sess.run(init)

 # Training cycle
 for epoch in range(training_epochs):
    avg_cost = 0.
    total_batch = batch_size
    # Loop over all batches
    #for i in range(total_batch):
    for batch_x, batch_y in get_batch(inputX, inputY, batch_size):
        # Run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
        _, c, _l1, _pred = sess.run([optimizer, cost, l1, pred], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
        # Compute average loss
        avg_cost += c / total_batch
    # Display logs per epoch step
    if epoch % display_step == 0:
        print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "cost=", "{:.9f} ".format(avg_cost))
        #print(_l1, _pred)
print("Optimization Finished!")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! So, I scaled my datas but the cost still very high, I also tried smaller weight init (0.01 instead of 0.1). Sorry for asking but, do you have an example of get_batch function ? I'm kinda lost with the batchs...

Comment: Thank you ! I'll try to understand to use it again !

Answer (score 2):

I have already had a similar problem of a very high cost reached after a few training steps, and then the cost remaining constant there. For me it was a kind of overflow, with the gradients too big and creating Nan values quite early in training. I solved it by starting with a smaller learning rate (potentially much smaller), until the cost and gradients become more reasonable (a few dozen steps), and then back to a regular one (higher at the start, potentially decaying).

See [my answer to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44307423/7456923) for a similar case that was solved just by taking a smaller learning rate on start.

You can also clip your gradients to avoid this problem, using [tf.clip_by_value](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/train/gradient_clipping). It sets a minimum and maximum value to your gradients, which avoids to have huge ones that send your weights straight to Nan after the first few iterations. To use it (with min and max at -1 and 1, which is probably too tight), replace

```
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)
```

by

```
opt= tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)

gvs = opt.compute_gradients(cost)
capped_gvs = [(tf.clip_by_value(grad, -1., 1.), var) for grad, var in gvs]
optimizer = opt.apply_gradients(capped_gvs)
```

Comment: Ty, I'll check and try it. Clip my gradient ?

Comment: Ty, I'll try this !

Comment: I've edited my post to explain. Also, I don't know your dataset, but I doubt very much that you get an accuracy > 0: you're doing a regression and want the predicted float to be equal to the true float value, that's nearly impossible ! If you train well you'll always be very close, but you won't have the exact value. You should use some rounding or something like that

Comment: Well, I have an error message with "ValueError: None values not supported." at this line :  capped_gvs = [(tf.clip_by_value(grad, -1., 1.), var) for grad, var in gvs]

Comment: I use this dataset : https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data. For the accuracy, I'm aware of this problem, that's the next on my list

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have time right now to debug it, but you should try using a much smaller learning rate for a while, to see if it gets you below your current cost.

Comment: Don't worry, it still really kind of you to take time for helping me ! I still try to understand how it work to fix it. Thanks again

Comment: By the way, `clip_by_value` is probably not the best clipping option actually (because it changes the direction of the gradient), I would rather go for one of those using the L2 norm, for instance this one https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/clip_by_norm.