# How should be the data set of RBG images in the separable_conv2d function on tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

How should be the data set **train_x** of RBG images in the separable_conv2d function on tensorflow?

Are we going to organise the images as illustrated in the following figure?

For example if there are 10 images of type RGB and size 32 * 32, the size of train_x will be (32,32,3*10) !!?

[image]

Comment: I've edited your question and had to use Google Translate to adjust your French to English, please double check to make sure there are no errors, in future, please keep your question in English only. If you are struggling, feel free to use Google Translate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The separable_conv2d() has a `data_format` parameter. If you set it to `NHWC` then your input should be [10, 32, 32, 3]. If you set it to `NCHW` then your input should be [10, 3, 32, 32].

Comment: Therefore the input data structure is an array of matrix with the size 3*10, each T[i] contains a channel of the image, for example:

T [1] = R-channel of image 1
T [2] = G-channel of image 1
T [3] = B-channel of image 1
.
.
.
T [28] = R-channel of image 10
T [29] = G-channel of image 10
T [30] = B-channel of image 10

Comment: For NHWC the input data structure is an array of size 10. And each input t[i] contains a image of three dimensions [32, 32, 3]. In numpy for example, batch = np.random.normal(size=(10,32,32,3)), is the input data format you should feed.

Comment: Thank you vijay, I have another question if it will not bother you, how dividing this data set into batches?
cordially.

Comment: You can find get_batch() in the answer i posted in : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44646547/super-high-cost-tensorflow/44654000#44654000. Open up a thread, if there are specific issues, ill help you